# Копирование хэдера в качестве переменной

Tags: php

Разрабатываю сайт и столкнулся с проблемой, когда нужно один `<head>` подключить на разных страницах, но тупо копировать и вставлять - не вариант. Например, нужно будет поменять что-то или добавить. Так вот, чтобы не приходилось каждый раз это делать, можно ли как-то внести содержимое тега `<head>` в переменную и выводить на главной странице при помощи `<?php echo $header; ?>`? И как это правильно сделать?

Comment: ну вобщем, ты сам и ответил себе... объявляешь переменную header, складываешь туда содержимое тэга, и выводишь везде, где надо

Comment: а, ну могу добавить, что надо объявить ее в отдельном файле (скажем, `header.php`), и инклудить его везде, где надо вывести переменную (`require 'header.php'; echo $header;`)

Comment: а как "правильно" - зависит от того, на чем сайт разрабатываешь... у каждого "на чем" есть своё "как правильно" :)

Answer (score 0):

Как пример:

test.php

```html
<?php

class Head 
{

protected static $head = 'TestHead';
public static function getHead()
{
 return self::$head;
}
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title><? echo Head::getHead() ?></title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>

 </body> 
</html>
```

test2.php

```html
<? include_once "test.php" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title><? echo Head::getHead() ?></title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>

 </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно например так с помощью HEREDOC-синтаксиса в переменную записать хедер.

```
$header = <<< HEADER
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Заголовок</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
HEADER;
```

Объявить его в каком-нибудь файл и подключать. Либо просто вынести в отдельный файл и подключать его.

Answer (score 0):

J. Doe, ваш пример ему будет выводить один и тот же хедер. Если реализовать на ООП (хотя зачем тут ооп?), то вместо public static function getHead() надо что-то, типа конструктора, передавая в него параметры для каждой страницы. Примерно так:

```
public function __construct($head) {
    $this->head = $head;
}
```